# MyBatis - ResultHandler is not getting called when no rows are returned by the select statement

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am streaming  a ResultSet using ibatis session ResultHandler.

I have my own implementation of ResultHandler

```html
public class StreamResultHandler<T> implements ResultHandler
{
    private JobType<T> job;

    public StreamResultHandler(ReplicatorType<T> replicatorType)
    {
        this.job = replicatorType;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context)
    {
        T type = (T) context.getResultObject();
        job.callEndPointService(type);
    }
}
```

When my select statement doesn't have any rows returned, mybatis is not even calling handleResult method. I want to do some updates to database when no rows are not returned.

Is there a count/flag that specifies the number of rows ? How can I achieve this.

I am using mybatis-3.2.2.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why would it get called when no rows are returned? Isn't it doing just what you'd expect? No results - no call?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `count` to your `StreamResultHandler` implementation and increment it in the `handleResult()`. The total results handled will be available in the `count()` method as outlined below.

```
public class StreamResultHandler<T> implements ResultHandler
{
    private JobType<T> job;
    private int count;

    public StreamResultHandler(ReplicatorType<T> replicatorType)
    {
        this.job = replicatorType;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context)
    {
        T type = (T) context.getResultObject();
        job.callEndPointService(type);
        count++;
    }

    public int count()
    {
        return count;
    }

}
```